# What can be meant by "bandlimited"?

Tags: sampling, frequency, aliasing

[This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70881/50076) was a source of disagreement on whether "amplitude aliasing" can occur for a signal bandlimited to below half the sampling frequency. The question was closed before the disagreement was resolved. A key to the disagreement may be in the definition of "bandlimited".

**Is there a different way to define "bandlimited" other than via the frequency domain?**

**Edit**: since bumped - the source of confusion in the referenced question was the default SP assumption of basis functions, which are fixed-amplitude and fixed-frequency complex sines. What I'm asking is whether there are other such basis functions off of which one may define "bandlimited" - which would require an [alternative sampling theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422626/396854).

Comment: I would prefer this to be a new question. Alternatively, the existing answer can be deleted, since it doesn't answer the question as edited.

Comment: @MBaz It explains an alternative definition and contrasts with the accepted one - what is unanswered?

Comment: As for my answer, it's more of a survey than a mathematical proof, and there's plenty of survey-answers all over this network.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not without explicit clarification that you want to define it differently in the context of signal processing (and why cause that confusion?). For signal processing, "bandlimited" simply means the waveform in the frequency domain is limited to a specific range of frequencies (the "frequency band"), outside of which there is zero energy; the waveform has finite support in the frequency domain.

Comment: Hey Dan, I don't see how this answers the question?

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandlimiting   For signal processing, this is the definition of band-limiting.

Comment: This question, and my answer, were made in the referenced context, which I've now summarized to hopefully clear things up.

Answer (score -2):

Post's structured addressing an originally different formulation of the question, "agree" and "disagree" responding to "can a bandlimited signal amplitude-alias?" - but still answers the current question.

---

**Where I agree**

If the actual, continuous/analog signal has no continuous Fourier transform frequency components above $f_s / 2$, then *there can be no aliasing*. This is explained in detail in [Dan's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70884/50076).

Put differently, an $s(t)=A(t)\cos(\omega t)$ with amplitude $A(t)$ that samples to the [observed waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/segf3.png) would necessarily have CFT components above $f_s/2$, whereas we assume there are none.

---

**So why disagree?**

Because Fourier isn't alpha and omega. I said the signal is *bandlimited*, or *having a finite range of frequencies*; I never said these were *Fourier frequencies*.

Consider a pure tone, $f=64$; now picture its Fourier transform (or DFT). Nice, clean, single spike at $\pm 64$. Now modulate its amplitude: $A(t) \cos(32 \pi t),\ A(t)=\cos(\pi t)$, sample at $f_s = 1290$, take DFT:

[image]

A mess! Nonzero frequencies far beyond $64$. For continuous FT, not only do we see a higher frequency, but the original $f=64$ is *gone*, and we have $f=\pm 63.5, \pm 64.5$ - neither of which are in the non-AM waveform. And DFT isn't the only one delicate; if $A(t)$ weren't purely sinusoidal, FT too would get messy.

Is there a nicer, more intuitive representation? Sure - [EMD](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hilbert%E2%80%93Huang_transform): "instead of constant amplitude and frequency in a simple harmonic component, an IMF can have variable frequency **and amplitude** along the time axis." So amplitude gets *its own*, independent representation, instead of squeezing it along frequency as constants. This enables vastly *more intuitive* and *sensible* descriptions of a fixed frequency that happens to be amplitude-modulated.

---

**Does this matter in practice?**

Absolutely. Consider a damped swinging pendulum, whose measurements we have (assume without noise). *Don't* assume constant damping; just assume it never changes the cycle periods (left & right stop times). At what frequency is the pendulum swinging? Suppose it's actually 2 / sec, but we don't know that.

There's no way to spin the story or measure differently that wouldn't result in the Fourier interpretation telling us "it's 2 *and-some*!" And the "some" can be 4, 8, 40, or more - an entire nonzero distribution of these.

Does this make much sense? Do we get an accurate representation of the *physical process*? Absolutely not; there are no $f=8, 40$, and the other frequencies. These are what's *demanded* by Fourier bases assuming fixed amplitudes, and is precisely what this [warmly-received answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70395/50076) further illustrates.

With an *EMD lens*, however, we get a much cleaner and sensible representation: $A(t) \cos (4\pi t)$, with the *one frequency* of the actual source process being clearly captured, and amplitude can now be analyzed independently for various factors.

Let me repeat: **there are no higher (or lower) frequencies in the physical process**, and $\mathcal{F}$ will strongly beg to differ.

---

**My own application** is what motivated the question to begin with.

The goal is to preprocess EEG data as a "feature extraction" step before feeding it to a neural network for seizure classification. As such, it's critical I meaningfully interpret the interactions of used transforms with data.

Below are two different Continuous Wavelet Transform implementations applied to the same signal:

[image]

One clearly represents the right part's dip in amplitude, other doesn't. The waveform is two adjacent signals, $f=64, 1$, each with $N=129$ samples. So the *actual*, continuous / analog waveform is more accurately captured by one on the right. ... but *how do I know this, in practice*?

Of course if I know the data is *Fourier-bandlimited*, I can state with certainty that this is a 1Hz pure tone with an "imaging" effect, rather than an AM waveform. **But I cannot possibly know that**; Fourier frequencies aren't even 'actual' frequencies to begin with, as previously noted, so the only way to know if a signal is Fourier-bandlimited is to either have the source's mathematical function (good luck), or make a series of assumptions, apply filters, and be "sufficiently confident" the assumption holds.

What I *can* know is how bandlimited the *physcal process* is. For EEG, we're dealing with the brain, which we know to be capable of producing waves under a certain frequency (mostly <100Hz IIRC). If we strap on a device that samples at 10kHz, we'll undoubtedly get a DFT with nonzero normalized frequency components in thousands - which is absurd.

Thus we have a piece of information that's incompatible with a purely Fourier lens. If only we could avoid such 'artificial frequencies' by allowing amplitude to be represented independently... hello EMD.

Here's the truth: you either cannot tell me the physical process's, like one's [this waveform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70881/50076) may have emerged from, *Fourier* $f_\text{max}$, or it may cost you a lot to figure out. But you can tell me, from knowledge of the system, its *physical*, 'actual' $f_\text{max}$, which is precisely mathematically captured by decoupling frequency and amplitude representations as in EMD. If it's "*EMD-bandlimited*", it can very well be amplitude aliasing, and we can treat it accordingly.

---

**What this means for responders & why it matters**, in [Meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1710/50076).

---

**Mathematical formulation of "bandlimited"** wasn't the purpose of this question, but it's a valid inquiry of its own. Doubt I'll dedicate a Q&A to it so here briefly:

One must *restrict* what qualifies as "amplitude", $A(t)$, else it could be anything, including something that divides out whatever it modulates, making the definition useless. An intuitive restriction, aside continuity and differentiability, is $\mathcal{F}(A(t)) \ll \mathcal{F}e^{j\phi(t)}$ for

$$
s(t) = \sum_k A_k(t) e^{j\phi(t)}
$$

Then "bandlimited" would be defined over $\omega_k$:

$$
\omega_k (t) = \frac{d}{dt} \phi_k (t)
$$

Such construction is applied in [Daubechies et al](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Eingrid/publications/DM96.pdf) - page 538:

[image]

"Bandwidth" is defined over $\omega_k$ above - thus, so is **bandlimited**. A more rigorous formulation is given in [this paper](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ejianfeng/paper/synsquez.pdf):

[image]

Further explorations and applications in [Lilly & Olhede](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3834) and much other literature.

Comment: It's good to have an open mind, and Dan explained an interesting aspect of sampling inspired by your question. In real-world applications, you also need an engineering mindset, since theory only applies so far, and we have imperfect models. Engineers still manage to make useful devices, though. Your answer, though, is mostly incomprehensible rambling. If you rewrite this, and (first) define all terms (for example, "frequency" vs "Fourier frequency", and "amplitude aliasing"), and (second) show your reasoning and conclusions using mathematical models, then I promise to take a close look.

Comment: @MBaz My answer's not rigorous, as that'd require an entire publication, but I'd surely not call it "incomprehensible"; anyone with reasonable DSP background should grasp it. Nor is such rigor present in majority of other answers on this network, or can be expected of - though I'm pretty sure you can infer exactly what I mean if you read it.

Comment: I didn't read past the "Why Disagree" part yet as I have limited time today, but those statements that the higher frequency components do not exist and are just mythical "Fourier Frequencies" make it difficult to read further without being reconciled. Keep in mind that all "Frequencies" and the "Frequency Domain" is just a mathematical construction that we can easily associate with physical processes. The important thing is the math works, and when we find cases where no solution yet exists, then new math and new explanations are justified and welcomed.

Comment: @DanBoschen I'll wait until you've read the other half, and will gladly link further material I recently found that are explicitly based on the very distinction I'm making.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I read it- the issue is that in signal processing "frequencies" refers to what you distinguish as "Fourier Frequencies" so they are one and the same. Certainly if that is a unique distinction in your question- and if that is important- that should (and still could) be corrected in your original question to have it approach making any sense. Also your introductory example here showing what you describe as a pure tone is NOT a pure tone just as the Fourier Transform accurately represents. It has the frequency content as shown given is it a rectangular pulse of that tone--

Comment: As you extend that same pulse toward infinity, the Fourier Transform will approach the pure tone which that represents. The DFT accurately represents the frequency content of that pulse repeating in time. For practical application toward your underlying issue, the way this has been resolved in practice to best estimate the actual frequency content versus the artifacts introduced by the finite capture is through proper windowing of the waveform prior to taking the DFT. I hope that helps!

Comment: @DanBoschen It is a pure tone; you might've speed-read this - the DFT plot is of what's described in next sentence, else it'd be a perfect single spike. Further, I'm aware of everything else you've said, but you've done my speaking for me: FT and the frequency domain are _mathematical constructs_. They have their usefulness and meaningfulness, but no one to fit all.

Comment: "Frequency", by its general definition, has no ties to FT; it's "# of times a process repeats itself per unit time". i.e. $f$ in $s(t) = s(t + 1/f)$. The question then is what qualifies as "the process", and a conceptually accurate summary is rather lengthy, so I'll nutshell it: FT uses _fixed-amplitude_ bases in construction, EMD treats amplitude _independently_ (just like FT treats frequencies). For EMD amplitude is _decoupled_, so there are really _two_ "the process-es", and the _non-amplitude_ process in the pendulum example clearly has a single frequency.

Comment: @DanBoschen "not accurate with your own definition" - but it is. Your prior comment again invokes FT; an amplitude-decoupled approach can trivially represent $A(t) \cos(2 \pi f_0 t)$ without any $f > f_0$.

Comment: I agree with @MBaz's comment to the question about that this answer does not give a definition of *bandlimited* that a signal could be tested with to know whether it is bandlimited or not.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Wasn't the purpose of this Q&A, but it's a valid relevant inquiry of its own; provided material which can guide an answer.

Comment: "an amplitude-decoupled approach can trivially represent A(t)cos(2πf0t) without any f>f0." Sorry I don't follow this at all. The waveform is AM modulated with A(t). If we remove the AM (amplitude -decoupled) then we are left with a carrier of frequency f0, and the frequency will only be f0. This does not then mean that the combined waveform A(t)cos(2πf0t) only has the frequency content of f0, which appears to be suggested here. If we modulate the amplitude of a pendulum swinging with frequency f1 to change sinusoidally at f= f2, it too will contain the frequencies given by  f1+f2 and f1-f2.

Comment: @DanBoschen The combined signal would have _one_ frequency component. _In the decoupled construction_ - what this post is about. I cited respectable literature that uses such a definition of bandlimited. The combined signal has "multiple frequencies" in a _Fourier_ construction, i.e. _fixed-amplitude_ frequencies.

Comment: @DanBoschen May wish to check again that definition of phase, and what it _omits_ from operating on. (... A(t)). Then we take your very own formula [and...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJprw.png) one frequency. Where _you_ 'win' in this, as discussed earlier, is that the carrier (non-A(t)) frequency is now _different_, and _greater_ - where I win is that there's one frequency, and a variable amplitude.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Then following that logic a sinusoidally varying amplitude is just a varying amplitude, and doesn't have a frequency. So A(t) = cos(2 pi fa t) doesn't have a frequency.

Comment: @DanBoschen A(t) has a frequency, but it's not counted toward s(t)'s in s(t) = A(t) cos(...). We distinguish between the _modulator_ and the _carrier_; that the modulator is a sinusoid is but one possibility. Is this sloppy and outright useless? Yes, _if_ we don't restrict what qualifies as A(t) - and we do, as shown under "Mathematical formulation".