# Relationship between amplitude and sampling rate

Tags: sampling, python, amplitude

I'm loading a signal with librosa in python. With the original sample rate of 22050 Hz, i get the following waveplot:

[image]

When i choose to resample my signal with the sample rate of 512 Hz, i get the following waveplot:

[image]

My question is, how come the amplitude is less with 512 Hz than with 22050 Hz? I assume that since the interval at which we record the amplitude is larger at 512Hz, the values should be larger too.

Comment: Can you tell us what "loading with a sample rate" *means*? The signal you have in your computer already is sampled, so it has a sample rate. Are you just reinterpreting sample times? In that case, zoom in by a factor of 22050/512 in your upper plot and you'll see the lower.

Comment: By loading with a sample rate i mean loading and resampling it, yes. So by resampling it, my new amplitude intervals become: original interval / (22050/512)...or zoomed in. Thank you, i get it now

Comment: Could you **edit** your question to include that you mean resampling?

Comment: One of the factors, [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70884/50076)

Answer (score 4):

In order to resample without aliasing, the resampling process needs to apply an anti aliasing filter at the new Nyquist Frequency (or thereabouts). So chances are, your resampling process applied a low pass filter at 256 Hz or so and that removed A LOT of the energy.

Comment: If the OP takes the FFT of the original signal, and plots the magnitude it would give an idea of how much energy is in the higher frequency components.