# How is sampling affecting this sine wave?

Tags: python, sampling, aliasing, amplitude, anti-aliasing-filter

I am trying to create a sine wave in python, but when I graph it, it looks like this:

[image]

here is the code I used to make the signal:

```
c_freq = 1700 * 1000
fs = c_freq * 2
secs = 3
x = fs*secs

t = np.linspace(0, secs, x)
carrier = np.sin(t * c_freq * 2 * np.pi)
```

Why is the amplitude changing throughout the signal and how can I fix this?

Comment: We've had [fun](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70881/50076) with this one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I get it. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: increase your sampling rate.

Comment: Why is it a problem? The graph looks funny but everything you do with the data will stay work. Is this a cosmetic or technical issue ?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the amplitude changing throughout the signal

Because you are sampling it at oh so slightly less than `c_freq/2`.  Your `linspace` call generates `x` points that are evenly spaced between 0 and 3, with a spacing between them of `3 * c_freq * 2 / (3 * c_freq * 2 + 1)`.  This means that the phase that gets calculated is $\begin{bmatrix}0, \pi-\epsilon, 2\pi - 2\epsilon,\cdots,(n-1)\pi-\pi+\epsilon, n \pi - \pi\end{bmatrix}$ -- and that gives the result you see, with alternating numbers on a half-rotation envelope.

(Why does it do that?  Work it out -- it'll be good for you.  Start by looking at how linspace actually behaves, i.e. `linspace(0, 10, 10)`).

> and how can I fix this?

What's wrong with it?  What do you want?  If you want a pretty sine wave, you need to sample way more than twice the frequency, and everyone defines "pretty" differently, so there's no fixed number.  I usually use 100 points per cycle of a sine wave -- but that would get pretty time intensive given that you want to plot three seconds of a 1.7MHz sine wave.

Comment: `linspace(a,b,N)` has a spacing of `(b-a)/(N-1)`, there is one less segment than the number of nodes.