# Nyquist frequency Plotting Distortions

Tags: matlab, sampling, nyquist, distortion

I'm trying to plot some sinusoidal signals in Matlab.

But while frequency is getting higher (closing to fs/2), results are getting distorted.

I guess it's lack of my knowledge but distortion is starting soon. My peak points are getting away from the original amplitude.

What is the reason and how can I correct it?

Code is;

```
fs =441; %discrete *100 - Hz
%data
phase = 0;
A = 6;
f = 50; % *100 -Hz
%sampling
n=0:2/f*fs;
Ts=1/fs;
Tn=n*Ts;
%signal
Xn=A*cos(2*pi*f*Tn+phase*pi);
%plotting
stem(Tn,Xn)
figure;plot(Tn,Xn)
```

Normal signal; 1kHz @44100Hz
[image]

Distorted signal #1; 5kHz @44100Hz
[image]

Distorted signal #2; 15kHz @44100Hz
[image]

Distorted signal #3; 20kHz @44100Hz
[image]

Almost ok signal; 22050Hz @44100Hz
[image]

Comment: [Related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70907/50076)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid low time resolution is to upsample signals before whatever processing.

To answer this question I have modified the Mathworks example that downsamples DAB (audio) signals to match DVD (audio) rates, example available here:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/upfirdn.html

So Let's get started

```
close all;clear all;clc
```

**1.-** **Signal parameters**

```
fs1=44.2e3;Ts1=1/fs1;     % 22.624us 
f1=5e3;T1=1/f1;         % .2ms  

spf=500;  % samples per frame
```

**2.-** **Low pass filter parameters**

```
f_pass=21e3;f_stop=22e3;  % LPF start and stop frequencies have to be < fs1
Rp=1; % [dB] pass band ripple
Lstop=60; % [dB] pass band attenuation
```

**3.-** **Upsampling parameters**

```
fs2=4*fs1  % upsampling frequency
[L,M] = rat(fs2/fs1)
f_ = (fs1/2)*min(1/L,1/M)
```

**3.-** Generating signal `s1` same as `Sine1()`

**3.1.- `s1` values**

```
Sine1 = dsp.SineWave('Frequency',f1,'SampleRate',fs1,'SamplesPerFrame',spf);
s1=Sine1();
```

**3.2.-** `s1` **time reference**

```
t1=[0:1:spf-1]*Ts1;
```

**4.-** Building **low pass filers**

**4.1.-** **LPF1** with command `dsp.LowpassFilter`

```
LPF1= dsp.LowpassFilter('PassbandFrequency',f_pass, ...
                                     'StopbandFrequency',f_stop, ...
                                     'PassbandRipple',Rp , ...
                                     'StopbandAttenuation',Lstop, ...
                                     'SampleRate',fs2,  ...
                                     'FilterType','IIR');

fvtool(LPF1,'Analysis','freq')  % check H(f) of LPF1
```

[image]

**4.2.-** `LPF11` another low pass filter with quite the same parameters as `LPF1` and built with alternative command `designfilt`

```
% generating anti-aliasing filter LPF11
 LPF11= designfilt('lowpassfir', ...
                         'PassbandFrequency',.9*f_, ...
                         'StopbandFrequency',1.1*f_, ...
                         'PassbandRipple',3, ...     % Rp, ...
                         'StopbandAttenuation',40, ... % Lstop, ...
                         'DesignMethod','kaiserwin', ...
                         'SampleRate',fs2);
fvtool(LPF11,'Analysis','freq')  % check H(f) of LPF11
```

[image]

**5.-** Building **Spectrum Analyzers**

```
SA = dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer('PlotAsTwoSidedSpectrum',false, ...
                                          'SampleRate',4*fs1, ... % Sine1.SampleRate, ...
                                          'FrequencyResolutionMethod','WindowLength', ... 
                                          'FrequencyVectorSource','Property',...
                                          'FrequencyVector',[-5000 000],...
                                          'NumInputPorts',2,...
                                          'FrequencyResolutionMethod','RBW', ...
                                          'RBW',40, ...
                                          'FFTLength',4096, ...
                                          'ShowLegend',true, ...
                                          'YLimits',[-30,45]);

% an alternative Spectrum Analyzer I used to do some checks
% SA2 = dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer('PlotAsTwoSidedSpectrum',false, ...
%                                           'SampleRate',4*fs1, ... % Sine1.SampleRate, ...
%                                           'NumInputPorts',2,...
%                                           'ShowLegend',true, ...
%                                           'FrequencyResolutionMethod','WindowLength', ...  % 'RBW'
%                                           'FFTLengthSource','Auto', ... % 'Property', ...
%                                           'RBW',20, ...
%                                           'FFTLength',2048, ...
%                                           'WindowLength',128, ...
%                                           'TimeResolution',1e-4, ...
%                                           'YLimits',[-30,45]);
```

**6.-** **Filtering** `s1`

**6.1.- Without upsampling** : `s1` through filter `LPF1`

I have added a small amount of nose to `s1` and then it's useful to do some averaging

```
SA.ChannelNames = {'s1','LPF(s1)'};
y1avg=zeros(1,numel(s1));
for i = 1 : spf
s1n=s1; % + 0.1.*randn(Sine1.SamplesPerFrame,1);
    y1 = LPF1(s1n);
    SA(s1n,y1); % filtering 
     y1avg=.5*(y1avg+y1); % averaging  
end
release(SA)
```

[image]

```
figure
plot(t1,y1avg,'b');
hold on;grid on
stem(t1,y1avg,'b');
plot(t1,s1','r');
stem(t1,s1,'r');
xlim([10*T1 13*T1]);
xlabel('t1');title('s1(t) y2=avg(LPF(s1)) no ups-LPF1')
```

[image]

**6.2.-** **With upsampling** : `s1` through filter `LPF1`

```
h0=L*tf(LPF11);
s1up = upfirdn(s1,h0,L,M);
d1 = floor(((filtord(LPF11)-1)/2-(L-1))/L);
s1up = s1up(d1+1:end);
t1up = (0:(length(s1up)-1))/fs2;

figure
stem(t1up,s1up,'*')
hold on;grid on;
stem(t1,s1);
xlim([10*T1 13*T1]);
legend('s1 original','s1 resampled','Location','southeast')
hold off
```

[image]

upsampled `s1` before filter

```
SA.ChannelNames = {'s1','LPF(s1)'};
y1upavg=zeros(numel(s1up),1);
for i = 1 : spf
    y1up = LPF1(s1up);
    y1upavg=[y1upavg y1up];
    SA(s1up,y1up);
end
y1upavg(:,1)=[];  
y2up=mean(y1upavg,2); % averaging
release(SA)
```

[image]

original `s1` and averaged upsampled antialiased `y2` .

Antialiasing is another way to say low pass filtered when the low pass filter is trimmed to the input signal.

```
figure
plot(t1up,y2up,'b');
hold on;grid on
stem(t1up,y2up,'b');
plot(t1,s1','r');
stem(t1,s1,'r');
xlim([10*T1 13*T1]);
xlabel('t1');title('s1(t) y2=avg(LPF(s1))')
```

[image]

Repeating for `s2` `s3` `s4` shows that `s1` frequency can be really close to a good 'flat' filter frequency edges and yet avoid amplitude degradation if the signal is upsampled just before 1st filter.

In analog signal processing, as example RF microwave filtering with transmission-line built filters there's no need to 'condition' signals as shown here with upsamping, but it's certainly important to use anti-aliasing filters nevertheless.

I have included `LPF11` in addition to `LPF1` because while `LPF1` has the question specs and a cut-off half of the sampling frequency `fs1`, `LPF11` has cut-off just above the input carrier `s1` ; which is the best way to perform low pass filtering.

There's a lot of spectrum between `f1` and `fs1/2` 22kHz that is good practice to avoid into a low pass filter intended for carrier `f1` at just 5kHz .

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 4):

It's simply a drawing artifact. You are plotting the wave form by connecting the individual samples with straight lines. That's wrong.

The values between samples can be determined through sinc interpolation, not through linear interpolation. The difference between the two becomes more and more visible as the frequency increases.